# I want to write my spark dataset to phoenix tables,Can anybody help me in this?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I have written the following code but its not working.

```
df.write().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(ImmutableMap.of("zkUrl", clientProp.getProperty("zookeeper.url"), "table", "mdr_rec.kafka_offsets")).save();
```

I am getting following error:

```
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the whole stack trace that would be very helpful